# Use CppADCodeGen with CMake FetchContent or ExternalProject

Tags: c++, c, git, cmake, autodiff

I am not good with CMake, and I cannot find good explanations about how to use its `FetchContent` functionality. Indeed, most repositories seem to require different treatment, and the rules of such treatment defy my comprehension.

That said, here is my problem. I would like to use *[CppADCodeGen](https://github.com/joaoleal/CppADCodeGen)* in my project using CMake `FetchContent`. Here is my code:

```
include(FetchContent)

message(STATUS "Fetching eigen...")
FetchContent_Declare(
  eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG 3.4.0
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
option(EIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET OFF)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)

message(STATUS "Fetching cppad...")
FetchContent_Declare(
  cppad
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD.git
  GIT_TAG 20210000.8
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cppad)

message(STATUS "Fetching cppadcodgen...")
FetchContent_Declare(
  cppadcodgen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/joaoleal/CppADCodeGen.git
  GIT_TAG v2.4.3
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cppadcodgen)
```

Here is the output and the errors I get:

```
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-11 - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Fetching eigen...
[cmake] -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11
[cmake] -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11 - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_std=cpp03
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_std=cpp03 - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically
[cmake] -- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically - Success
[cmake] -- Standard libraries to link to explicitly: none
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_WERROR
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_WERROR - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_pedantic
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_pedantic - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wall
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wall - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wextra
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wextra - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wundef
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wundef - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcastalign
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcastalign - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcharsubscripts
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcharsubscripts - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnonvirtualdtor
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnonvirtualdtor - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wunusedlocaltypedefs
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wunusedlocaltypedefs - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wpointerarith
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wpointerarith - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wwritestrings
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wwritestrings - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wformatsecurity
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wformatsecurity - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshorten64to32
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshorten64to32 - Failed
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wlogicalop
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wlogicalop - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wenumconversion
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wenumconversion - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcpp11extensions
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcpp11extensions - Failed
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wdoublepromotion
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wdoublepromotion - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshadow
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshadow - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnopsabi
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnopsabi - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnovariadicmacros
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnovariadicmacros - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnolonglong
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnolonglong - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnochecknew
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnochecknew - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnocommon
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnocommon - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fstrictaliasing
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fstrictaliasing - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd981
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd981 - Failed
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd2304
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd2304 - Failed
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_STRICTANSI
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_STRICTANSI - Failed
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Qunusedarguments
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Qunusedarguments - Failed
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_ansi
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_ansi - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP
[cmake] -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP - Success
[cmake] -- Looking for a Fortran compiler
[cmake] -- Looking for a Fortran compiler - /usr/bin/f95
[cmake] -- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
[cmake] -- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/f95 - skipped
[cmake] -- Checking whether /usr/bin/f95 supports Fortran 90
[cmake] -- Checking whether /usr/bin/f95 supports Fortran 90 - yes
[cmake] -- Found unsuitable Qt version "5.12.8" from /usr/bin/qmake
[cmake] -- Qt4 not found, so disabling the mandelbrot and opengl demos
[cmake] -- Found CHOLMOD: /usr/include/suitesparse  
[cmake] -- Found UMFPACK: /usr/include/suitesparse  
[cmake] -- Found KLU: /usr/include/suitesparse  
[cmake] -- Performing Test SUPERLU_HAS_GLOBAL_MEM_USAGE_T
[cmake] -- Performing Test SUPERLU_HAS_GLOBAL_MEM_USAGE_T - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test SUPERLU_HAS_CLEAN_ENUMS
[cmake] -- Performing Test SUPERLU_HAS_CLEAN_ENUMS - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test SUPERLU_HAS_GLOBALLU_T
[cmake] -- Performing Test SUPERLU_HAS_GLOBALLU_T - Success
[cmake] -- Found SuperLU: /usr/include/superlu (found suitable version "5.0", minimum required is "4.0") 
[cmake] -- Checking for one of the modules 'hwloc'
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_HWLOC_PARENT_MEMBER
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_HWLOC_PARENT_MEMBER - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_HWLOC_CACHE_ATTR
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_HWLOC_CACHE_ATTR - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_HWLOC_OBJ_PU
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_HWLOC_OBJ_PU - Success
[cmake] -- Looking for hwloc_bitmap_free in hwloc
[cmake] -- Looking for hwloc_bitmap_free in hwloc - found
[cmake] -- A version of Pastix has been found but pastix_nompi.h does not exist in the include directory. Because Eigen tests require a version without MPI, we disable the Pastix backend.
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- Configured Eigen 3.4.0
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- Available targets (use: make TARGET):
[cmake] -- ---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake] -- Target   |   Description
[cmake] -- ---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake] -- install  | Install Eigen. Headers will be installed to:
[cmake] --          |     <CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/<INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR>
[cmake] --          |   Using the following values:
[cmake] --          |     CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: /usr/local
[cmake] --          |     INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR:  include/eigen3
[cmake] --          |   Change the install location of Eigen headers using:
[cmake] --          |     cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=yourprefix
[cmake] --          |   Or:
[cmake] --          |     cmake . -DINCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR=yourdir
[cmake] -- doc      | Generate the API documentation, requires Doxygen & LaTeX
[cmake] -- blas     | Build BLAS library (not the same thing as Eigen)
[cmake] -- uninstall| Remove files installed by the install target
[cmake] -- ---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake] -- 
[cmake] -- Fetching cppad...
[cmake] CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/cppad-src/CMakeLists.txt:20 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
[cmake]   Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
[cmake]   CMake.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
[cmake]   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) at build/_deps/cppad-src/CMakeLists.txt:35 (PROJECT):
[cmake]   Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
[cmake]   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
[cmake]   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   The following variable(s) would be set to empty:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_cplusplus_201100_ok
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_cplusplus_201100_ok - Success
[cmake] -- cppad_cplusplus_201100_ok = 1
[cmake] -- cmake_install_datadir = share
[cmake] -- cmake_install_docdir = NOTFOUND
[cmake] -- cmake_install_includedirs = include
[cmake] -- cmake_install_libdirs = lib
[cmake] -- cppad_prefix = /usr/local
[cmake] -- cppad_postfix = NOTFOUND
[cmake] -- cppad_cxx_flags = 
[cmake] -- cppad_profile_flag = NOTFOUND
[cmake] -- cppad_testvector = cppad
[cmake] -- cppad_max_num_threads = 48
[cmake] -- cppad_tape_id_type = unsigned int
[cmake] -- cppad_tape_addr_type = unsigned int
[cmake] -- cppad_debug_which = debug_all
[cmake] -- include_eigen = false
[cmake] -- include_adolc = false
[cmake] -- include_ipopt = false
[cmake] -- include_cppadcg = false
[cmake] -- colpack_prefix = NOTFOUND
[cmake] -- sacado_prefix = NOTFOUND
[cmake] -- fadbad_prefix = NOTFOUND
[cmake] -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -g
[cmake] -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -DNDEBUG
[cmake] -- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
[cmake] -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
[cmake] -- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")  
[cmake] -- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components: thread 
[cmake] -- boost_prefix = /usr
[cmake] -- Found /usr/include
[cmake] -- Found /usr/lib
[cmake] -- Performing Test compiler_has_conversion_warn
[cmake] -- Performing Test compiler_has_conversion_warn - Success
[cmake] -- compiler_has_conversion_warn = 1
[cmake] -- cppad_boostvector = 0
[cmake] -- cppad_cppadvector = 1
[cmake] -- cppad_eigenvector = 0
[cmake] -- cppad_stdvector = 0
[cmake] -- cppad_cplusplus_201100_ok = 1
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_has_gettimeofday
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_has_gettimeofday - Success
[cmake] -- cppad_has_gettimeofday = 1
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_tape_id_type_is_unsigned
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_tape_id_type_is_unsigned - Success
[cmake] -- cppad_tape_id_type_is_unsigned = 1
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_tape_addr_type_is_unsigned
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_tape_addr_type_is_unsigned - Success
[cmake] -- cppad_tape_addr_type_is_unsigned = 1
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_max_num_threads_is_integer_ge_4
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_max_num_threads_is_integer_ge_4 - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_has_mkstemp
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_has_mkstemp - Success
[cmake] -- cppad_has_mkstemp = 1
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_has_tmpnam_s
[cmake] -- Performing Test cppad_has_tmpnam_s - Failed
[cmake] -- cppad_has_tmpnam_s = 0
[cmake] -- soversion = 712.8
[cmake] -- Not Windows system so building shared cppad_lib
[cmake] -- make check_example_abs_normal: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_atomic_two: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_atomic_three: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_chkpoint_two: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_graph: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_general: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_get_started: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_json: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_multi_thread_openmp: available
[cmake] -- pthread library path = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread_barrier_wait in pthread
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread_barrier_wait in pthread - found
[cmake] -- make check_example_multi_thread_pthread: available
[cmake] -- Performing Test boost_multi_thread_ok
[cmake] -- Performing Test boost_multi_thread_ok - Success
[cmake] -- make check_example_multi_thread_bthread: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_multi_thread: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_optimize: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_print_for: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_sparse: available
[cmake] -- make check_example_utility: available
[cmake] -- make check_example: available
[cmake] -- make check_introduction: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more_deprecated_atomic_two: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more_deprecated_chkpoint_one: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more_deprecated: available
[cmake] -- make check_det_by_minor_c: available
[cmake] -- make check_det_by_minor_cpp: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more_compare_c: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more_debug_rel: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more_cppad_for_tmb: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more_general: available
[cmake] -- make check_test_more: available
[cmake] -- make check_speed_cppad: available
[cmake] -- make check_speed_double: available
[cmake] -- make check_speed_example: available
[cmake] -- make check_speed_program: available
[cmake] -- make check_speed_xpackage: available
[cmake] -- make check_speed: available
[cmake] -- make check: avialable
[cmake] CMake Error at build/_deps/cppad-src/CMakeLists.txt:452 (ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET):
[cmake]   ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET cannot create target "uninstall" because another target
[cmake]   with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
[cmake]   created in source directory
[cmake]   "project/build/_deps/eigen-src".  See documentation for
[cmake]   policy CMP0002 for more details.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Fetching cppadcodgen...
[cmake] CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
[cmake]   Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
[cmake]   CMake.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
[cmake]   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) at build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/CMakeLists.txt:20 (PROJECT):
[cmake]   Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
[cmake]   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
[cmake]   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   The following variable(s) would be set to empty:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR
[cmake]     PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
[cmake] -- Found CppAD: project/build/_deps/cppad-src/include (Required is at least version "20200000.1") 
[cmake] CMake Error at build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/cmake/FindCppAD.cmake:86 (FILE):
[cmake]   FILE STRINGS file
[cmake]   "project/build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/CPPAD_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/cppad/configure.hpp"
[cmake]   cannot be read.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/CMakeLists.txt:42 (FIND_PACKAGE)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/cmake/FindCppAD.cmake:99 (MESSAGE):
[cmake]   Found CppAD version '' but at least version '20200000.1' is required
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/CMakeLists.txt:42 (FIND_PACKAGE)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**Is anyone able to achieve the above goal on their machine? If yes, would they kindly share how they did it?** In the above error messages there are several errors, and I have already tried some solutions, but none of them worked -- I will not list them because they are no use mentioning!

**EDIT**

@dlivshen When I integrated my library with a bigger project, I had more problems due to conflicting target names. This is because I used `FetchContent` to get *Eigen*. So I decided to obtain it using `ExternalProject`, and for this purpose I added these lines to the *CMakeLists.txt.in* file you proposed in your solution:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG 3.4.0
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/eigen
    -DEIGEN_BUILD_DOC
    OFF
    -DBUILD_TESTING
    OFF
    -DEIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET
    OFF
    -DEIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG
    OFF)
```

Then, in order to use *Eigen* I have to necessarily add `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/eigen/include/eigen3` to the `target_include_directories` command. This is in contrast to when I used `FetchContent` whereby I only needed to add `Eigen3::Eigen` to the `target_link_libraries` command. **This approach is not possible with `ExternalProject`: is this statement correct? If not, how can I achieve it?**

Comment: The problem is that `CppADCodeGen` requires an already installed version of `CppAD` (We can see it in the `FIND_PACKAGE` statement inside `CppADCodeGen`'s CMakeLists.txt). To quickly fix this you can install `CppAD` manually before reloading you cmake. For a more robust solution I'd recommend using a more sophisticated dependency management system such as `conan` or install the project using `ExternalProject` mofule of cmake.

Comment: @dlivshen Thank you for your answer. I suspected that the problem was related to the fact that `CppAD` was not installed system-wide. However, this is something I would like to avoid: I would like the user to only need CMake, a compiler, and Git to work on my project. If you claim that `ExternalProject` is the only possible solution to achieve what I desire, then, if you submit a clean, working, "modern CMake" answer, I will be more than happy to accept it!

Comment: @dlivshen FYI, I started a 50 reputation bounty for this question!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response I had some busy days.. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problems Overview

As seen in the output you've provided, there are 2 problems:

1. There is a target name conflict between probably `CppAD` and `eigen`. They both have the `uninstall` target. It can be seen here:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at build/_deps/cppad-src/CMakeLists.txt:452 (ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET):
[cmake]   ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET cannot create target "uninstall" because another target
[cmake]   with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
[cmake]   created in source directory
[cmake]   "project/build/_deps/eigen-src".
```

2. `cppadcodgen` requires an already installed version of `CppAD`. It can be seen in the error message which tells us that an invalid version was found:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/cmake/FindCppAD.cmake:99 (MESSAGE):
[cmake]   Found CppAD version '' but at least version '20200000.1' is required
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   build/_deps/cppadcodgen-src/CMakeLists.txt:42 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

## Solution

Unfortunately, currently we can't use `FetchContent` to deal with those problems, because:

1. There isn't any mechanism that would allow us distinguishing conflicting targets (for example a "namespace" prefix could be a solution and then there could be 2 targets `eigen:uninstall` and `cppad:uninstall`).
2. We can't build the dependent target during configuration step.

Instead we'll use the `ExternalProject` module. Here's a possible solution:

```
include(FetchContent)

message(STATUS "Fetching eigen...")
FetchContent_Declare(
  eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG 3.4.0
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
option(EIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET OFF)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(cppad
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD.git
  GIT_TAG           20210000.8
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS -Dcppad_prefix:STRING=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad
)

ExternalProject_Add(cppadcodgen
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/joaoleal/CppADCodeGen.git
  GIT_TAG           v2.4.3
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS -DCPPAD_HOME:STRING=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad/include -DGOOGLETEST_GIT:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppadcodegen
  DEPENDS cppad
)
```

I used the following commands to test it:

```sh
mkdir cmake-build
cd !$
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

### Explanation

Most of the parameters are exactly the same as used in `FetchContent`. The only differences are:

- We install `cppad` to the build directory instead of a system wide directory, so the whole process will be self-contained. It is achieved by setting the `cppad_prefix` cache variable to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad` in the `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS` option.
- We make sure that `cppadcodgen` succeeds finding `CppAD` by setting the `CPPAD_HOME` cache variable to the include directory (which is `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad/include`) and also setting this target to run after `CppAD` is installed using the `DEPENDS` option.
- `cppadcodgen` sets the test targets as well and it will fail if it cannot find Google Test. Fortunately they provide an option to download Google Test using the `GOOGLETEST_GIT` option which we set to `ON`.
- Finally, we set to install `cppadcodgen` inside the build directory, by setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable.

Note that I haven't touched `eigen` because I don't know what would be the exact usage and it didn't fail the build. It could be easily modified to be `ExternalProject` as written above if needed.

More information on `ExternalProject` can be found in Cmake's [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add).

## Consuming the Dependencies

In order to consume the dependencies we have to perform some modifications.
Let's take as example the main file from `CppADCodeGen` [wiki page](https://github.com/joaoleal/CppADCodeGen/wiki) and try to compile it with our solution:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>
#include <cppad/cg.hpp>

using namespace CppAD;
using namespace CppAD::cg;

int main() {
    // use a special object for source code generation
    typedef CG<double> CGD;
    typedef AD<CGD> ADCG;

    /***************************************************************************
     *                               the model
     **************************************************************************/

    // independent variable vector
    CppAD::vector<ADCG> x(2);
    x[0] = 2.;
    x[1] = 3.;
    Independent(x);

    // dependent variable vector 
    CppAD::vector<ADCG> y(1);

    // the model
    ADCG a = x[0] / 1. + x[1] * x[1];
    y[0] = a / 2;

    ADFun<CGD> fun(x, y); // the model tape

    /***************************************************************************
     *                        Generate the C source code
     **************************************************************************/

    /**
     * start the special steps for source code generation for a Jacobian
     */
    CodeHandler<double> handler;

    CppAD::vector<CGD> indVars(2);
    handler.makeVariables(indVars);

    CppAD::vector<CGD> jac = fun.SparseJacobian(indVars);

    LanguageC<double> langC("double");
    LangCDefaultVariableNameGenerator<double> nameGen;

    std::ostringstream code;
    handler.generateCode(code, langC, jac, nameGen);
    std::cout << code.str();
}
```

Note that `ExternalProject_Add` command runs on build time, and we would like to find our dependencies already during Cmake reload time. So unfortunately we'll have to do a dirty trick to force `ExternalProject_Add` to run on Cmake reload time:

1. We'll move the `ExternalProject_Add` commands into a helper, `CMakeLists.txt.in` file.
2. We'll configure the `CMakeLists.txt.in` so the output paths of the libraries will remain inside our build directory.
3. We'll invoke `execute_process` (which run on cmake reload time) to execute the build process of the helper `CMakeLists.txt.in`
4. We'll find our libraries and consume them. Note that we can't use the modern Cmake targets syntax, as the whole process is being run in a sub-process and we don't have access to the created target. But even if we didn't run it inside a sub process, `ExternalProject` targets' type is utility which can't be used in commands such as `target_link_libraries`. So we'll use the custom paths we created for the dependencies and pass them to `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories` commands.

The end results are displayed below:

**CMakeLists.txt.in**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(deps-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(cppad
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD.git
  GIT_TAG           20210000.8
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS -Dcppad_prefix:STRING=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad
)

ExternalProject_Add(cppadcodgen
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/joaoleal/CppADCodeGen.git
  GIT_TAG           v2.4.3
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS -DCPPAD_HOME:STRING=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad/include -DGOOGLETEST_GIT:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppadcodegen
  DEPENDS cppad
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
include(FetchContent)

message(STATUS "Fetching eigen...")
FetchContent_Declare(
  eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG 3.4.0
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTING OFF)
option(EIGEN_LEAVE_TEST_IN_ALL_TARGET OFF)
option(EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen)

# Configure the helper CMakeLists with the dependencies
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps-build/CMakeLists.txt)

# Build it
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} .
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps-build)

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps-build)       

# Find cppad_lib's path
find_library(cppad_lib cppad_lib HINTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad/lib REQUIRED)
      
# Create our target
add_executable(main
    main.cpp)
    
target_link_libraries(main ${cppad_lib})
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad/include
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppadcodegen/include)
```

As before, I used the following commands to test it:

```sh
mkdir cmake-build
cd !$
cmake ..
cmake --build .
./main
```

The solution is based on [this](https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/) post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer! I have tested this code, and to use _CppADCodeGen_ in different targets I have to add both `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppad/include` and `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cppadcodegen/include` to their `target_include_directories` commands. Is this correct? I thought I should only have required to add `cppadcodegen` to their `target_link_libraries` command, but this is not the case: indeed, when I run CMake it cannot find the include directories (whereas it does when I add them via `target_include_directories` as above)!

Comment: Also, I get this error: `[build] /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcppadcodegen` when I add `cppadcodegen` to `target_link_libraries`. In other words, is the approach via `target_include_directories` the correct one? Or should `target_link_libraries` be the way to go, but I am making mistakes somewhere else?

Comment: See my edited answer, I hope it explains stuff better.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly! I have tried to repeat the same process with the Eigen library using `ExternalProject_Add`, but I am not sure whether I did it correctly. I have edited my question: would you kindly confirm if my understanding is correct?