# Symbol lookup error: Using precompiled binary CasADI in C++ with cmake

Tags: c++, nonlinear-optimization, casadi

I want to use casadi with c++ for optimal control problems. Therefore, I want to include it using the binary with cmake. I am on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine. My cmake version is 3.16.3. My gcc version is 11.1.0.
I followed the following example: [Integrate pre-compiled libraries into C++ codebase with CMake ExternalProject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489173/integrate-pre-compiled-libraries-into-c-codebase-with-cmake-externalproject/71546749#71546749) and also added this flag

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

for compiling into my CMakeLists.txt https://groups.google.com/g/casadi-users/c/xIw4U6Rymps?pli=1

My code structures as follows (as in the exmaple):

- main.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt
- external/CMakeLists.txt
- build/

I build the exe as follows in the build folder:

```
cmake ..
```

```
make
```

and then executing the generated exe:

```
./main
```

It compiles without any problem but when executing i receive the following error message:

```
./main: symbol lookup error: ./main: undefined symbol: _ZN6casadi6MatrixINS_6SXElemEE4_symERKSsRKNS_8SparsityE
```

It only complains, when adding the SX Casadi symbols. Without them everything works! I think it is some sort of linking error.
Thanks for your help. I appreciate every help :) . I post below my code.

## main.cpp:

```
#include <casadi/casadi.hpp>

using namespace casadi;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    casadi_printf("This works! \n");

    
    SX x = SX::sym("x");
    SX z = SX::sym("z");

    return 0;
}
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# some default target
add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
# Configure and build external project
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external)
execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external
)
execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external
)

# find and link externals
find_package(casadi REQUIRED HINTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/external/casadi/src/casadi-3.5.5/casadi)
target_link_libraries(main casadi)
```

## external/CMakesLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(external)
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
        casadi-3.5.5
        URL https://github.com/casadi/casadi/releases/download/3.5.5/casadi-linux-py39-v3.5.5-64bit.tar.gz
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/casadi)
```

I tried:
including an older binary of casadi, removing and adding the flag

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

in both CMakeLists.txt

Comment: the missing symbol demangles as `casadi::Matrix<casadi::SXElem>::_sym(std::string const&, casadi::Sparsity const&)` are you sure that this library reqiures `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`?

Comment: When I remove this flag I receive the following error: [100%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `casadi::GenericMatrix<casadi::Matrix<casadi::SXElem> >::sym(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, casadi::Sparsity const&)':

Comment: and https://groups.google.com/g/casadi-users/c/xIw4U6Rymps?pli=1 suggests to include that flag.